# Error when converting argument in MPI program

Tags: c, mpi

i'm doing my MPI exercise now. In my work, i want to calculate the factorial of N, so i passed N by the second argument in the command line, all my code go fine except the line that i tried to convert from char* to int (this works with one process), please give me some advices in this situation, here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

   if(argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "\nYou must follow this format to run the program: [Program's name] [N]");
        exit(0);
        MPI_Finalize();
    }

    long int n = 1;

    n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10); // <-- problem happens here

    // Initialize MPI
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // Receive the whole size and id of each rank
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if(rank == 0){
        // Process for master
        master(n);
    }
    else{
        // Process for slaves
        slave();
    }


    // Finish MPI
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 1;
```

}

Thank you all for reading my post, any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do anything with `argv` and `argc` before the call to `MPI_Init`. In fact you should call `MPI_Init` as soon as possible. Most certainly do not call `MPI_Finalize` before `MPI_Init`.

To cite the standard:

> Certain implementations use the (inout) argc, argv arguments of the C
>   version of MPI_INIT in order to propagate values for argc and argv to
>   all executing processes.

Just move your `MPI_Init` call at the beginning of `main`.

Comment: Sorry, but after changing my code i still face the problem called "STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION" and the problem happens on the line:
n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

Comment: Have you used a debugger or *printf-debugging* to determine the conent of `argv[1]`?

Comment: Thank you sir, i have solved my problems after increasing the size of my array which hold my data when sending to slaves (The problem here is that my old array can't hold enough data export from my Big Int variable ( i use GMP)). I think i have to make some improve in my code by changing the static array to dynamic (i used to face some problems when sending pointer through send functions of mpi so i have to change all my array to static). Anyway, thank you very much sir.

Comment: @huynguyen I'm glad to be of help. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.